# Finding the constant of integration in differential equations given conditions of $y$ and $x$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve a differential equation and find the constant of integration given the conditions that $y \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$.  Given this condition I am unsure how to proceed on solving for the constant of integration.

I have the following D.E:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}-\frac{1}{x^2}y=\frac{1}{x^2},$$

which I have solved to be

$$y=Ce^{-\frac{1}{x}}-1.$$

I am now not sure how to proceed to solve for these conditions, if they were given numbers I would plug them into the formula and solve for $C$.  Here the quantity given is $\infty$ and $0$ and I think this is what is throwing me off.

I need to find a value of $C$ that will make $y=0$ but I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: In your first sentence you said you need to find a value of $C$ that will make $y\rightarrow 0$ as $x\rightarrow +\infty$, but in your last sentence you did something else.

Comment: e^(1/infinity) approaches to one giving c=1
As
0=c-1 i an sorry i can't give a better explanation because i am using my mobile to comment

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  I was working through 2 questions to use as examples and decided on one but got the conditions mixed up at the end, I have amended the question, cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you solved for $y$ correctly, you have that there exists some $C\in \Bbb R$ such that for all $x\in I$ (where $I$ is some interval), $y(x)=Ce^{-1/x}-1$.

Now you wish that $\lim \limits_{x\to +\infty}y(x)=0$.

Since $\lim \limits_{x\to +\infty}y(x)=Ce^{\lim \limits _{\large {x \to +\infty}}}-1=Ce^0-1=C-1$, you wish for $C$ to be $1$.

Therefore $y:I\to \Bbb R, x\mapsto e^{-1/x}-1$ and you can take $I$ to be any non trivial interval contained in $\Bbb R\setminus \{0\}$.